# How can I hide a column in a jQuery datatables based on a user role

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, datatables

I have a jQuery datatables implemented and it's working just fine. However, based on a user role, I would like to hide a column. To fix this, in Rails, I can set the conditional within a view/template. But that doesn't' work because on each request I get an alert telling me about for how many rows data is missing to be pulled into. Any ideas as to how to fix this? Much appreciated.
Alek

Comment: What have you tried to hide the column?

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html

Comment: Not really, my implementation requires user to be logged in, and based on that fact a column should be shown or hidden. I really don't want to let all users choose hide/show functionality.