# MVC 5 & Jquery DataTables Column display based on user Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables, user-roles

Using Jquery Datatables in an MVC 5 project. Also using Datatables.MVC5 helper which is making the whole task easier and followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa) to help set it all up for MVC Server Side processing.

I am trying to display button columns i.e. Edit | Delete | as the first two columns based on User Role. These buttons would call my normal MVC Controller.

I can create the buttons, I can not work out how to handle the role checking. My previous client side was easy with Razor Syntax, a lot more tricky now using DataTables.

My Current Table.

```
        $(function () {
        assetListVM = {
            dt: null,
            init: function () {
                dt = $('#assetdatatable').DataTable({
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "DisplayLength": 25,
                    "ajax": {
                        "type": "POST", // Required to change from 'GET' as this produced server error query string length too long.
                        "url": "@Url.Action("Get","Demo")",
                        "data": // Allows us to return extra data object to controller
                            function (d) {
                                d.excelExport = $("#excelExport").val();
                            }
                    },
                    "scrollY": viewheight, // Calculated to help ensure table is fitting max area of screen with out dropping off screen.
                    "colReorder": true,
                    "select": true,
                    "stateSave": true,
                    "dom": 'fBrtip',
                    "lengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],
                    "buttons": [
                        "pageLength",
                        "copy",
                        "excel"
                        ],
                    "columns": [
// HERE I need to check user Role and choose if to display column or not.
// I have tried Razor @if (User.IsInRole("Sausage")) { }
                        {
                            "title": "button column"
                            "data": "AssetID",
                            "className": 'details_button',
                            "render": function (AssetID)
                            {
                                return '<a class="btn-xs btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" href=/Demo/Details/' + AssetID +'></a>';
                                }
                            },
                        { "title": "AssetID", "data": "AssetID" },
                        { "title": "SIM", "data": "SIM" },
                        { "title": "IMEI", "data": "IMEI" },
                        { "title": "Software", "data": "LoggedOnSoftware" },
                        { "title": "Soft No", "data": "LoggedOnSoftwareVerNo" },
                        { "title": "Last Reset", "data": "LastResetType" },
                        {
                            "title": "Last Log", "data": "LastLogOnTime",
                            "render": function (LastLogOnTime) {
                                return (moment(LastLogOnTime).isValid()) ? moment(LastLogOnTime).format("DD MMM YY") : "-";
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "order": [[2, 'asc']]
                });
            }
        }

        // initialize the datatables
        assetListVM.init();
    });
```

In the column titled buttons column I have tried Razor syntax but not working unlike my previous tables for dummys projects which were all html based. I could send a viewbag object with current user role to view and then check against that, I just do not know how to perform if/else decissions within the table setup.

If anybody has any examples of something like this I could get to grips with or can point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

I have searched and checked the closest question I found was [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574635/how-can-i-hide-a-column-in-a-jquery-datatables-based-on-a-user-role).

Update:
Thanks to Jamie

here is my new working code, which based on current users role will hide the first column.

```
var RoleCheck = @(User.IsInRole("sausage") ? "true" : "false"); // new check for user role outside of Jquery DataTable function which will work.
            $(function () {
        assetListVM = {
            dt: null,
            init: function () {
                dt = $('#assetdatatable').DataTable({
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "processing": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "type": "POST", // Required to change from 'GET' as this produced server error query string length too long.
                        "url": "@Url.Action("Get","Demo")",
                        "data": // Allows us to return extra data object to controller
                            function (d) {
                                d.excelExport = $("#excelExport").val();
                            }
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [
                        {
                        "target": [0],
                        "visible": RoleCheck // new variable true or false based on user role.
                        }
                    ]
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "title": "button column"
                            "data": "AssetID",
                            "className": 'details_button',
                            "render": function (AssetID)
                            {
                                return '<a class="btn-xs btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" href=/Demo/Details/' + AssetID +'></a>';
                                }
                            },
                        { "title": "AssetID", "data": "AssetID" },
                        { "title": "SIM", "data": "SIM" },
                        { "title": "IMEI", "data": "IMEI" },
                        { "title": "Software", "data": "LoggedOnSoftware" },
                        { "title": "Soft No", "data": "LoggedOnSoftwareVerNo" },
                        { "title": "Last Reset", "data": "LastResetType" },
                        {
                            "title": "Last Log", "data": "LastLogOnTime",
                            "render": function (LastLogOnTime) {
                                return (moment(LastLogOnTime).isValid()) ? moment(LastLogOnTime).format("DD MMM YY") : "-";
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "order": [[2, 'asc']]
                });
            }
        }
        // initialize the datatables
        assetListVM.init();
    });
```

Comment: you can't make the validation part of the model?  Like a property `CanEdit` and set that value in your controller and check it `return CanEdit ? buttons : '';`

Comment: if `@Url.Action("Get","Demo")` is working then `return @(User.IsInRole("Sausage") ? 'button html' : "''");` should also work

Comment: @JamieD77 Thank you Jamie, that worked unfortunately at Row level, it hid the button, I want to not show the column at all.

Comment: well there are a few ways to remove a column.. would hiding it be ok?

Comment: @JamieD77 Yes I think that will do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might be able to add a columnDef for that column and set the visibility there.

```
"columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column
            "visible": @(User.IsInRole("Sausage") ? "true" : "false") // had syntactical error extra colon was there before question mark.
        }
    ]
```

setting variable instead of using inline Razor code.

```
var RoleCheck = @(User.IsInRole("Sausage") ? "true" : "false");


"columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column
            "visible": RoleCheck 
        }
    ]
```

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html

Comment: Thank you Jamie that was the way to go, but the problem was The Razor syntax just will not work in the script also it returne True or False. so using your method. outside the script  var RoleCheck = @(User.IsInRole("Galleos") ? "true" : "false");  and then in columnDefs "visible": RoleCheck if you could gladly amend your answer I will mark it as the way to go.

Comment: @AndyDonegan. Yeah it had the syntactical error ! I just fixed that :)